# WKWebView won't display the webpage I need it to

Tags: swift, uikit, wkwebview

Given the code below. I can't get the web page "https://baycare.clearstep.health/covid19" to show up. It shows up okay in Safari and I can get other pages to show up in the WKWebView. I have tried implementing all of the navigation and ui delegate methods to try and track down the problem but have failed to find anything.

The URL used to work, but the company has changed something and now it doesn't. Any help is appreciated.

The below is a complete program:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let controller = UIViewController()
            .setup { viewController in
                WKWebView(frame: viewController.view.bounds)
                    .setup {
                        viewController.view.addSubview($0)
                        $0.uiDelegate = WebViewUIDelegate.instance
                        $0.navigationDelegate = WebViewDelegate.instance
                        $0.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
                        $0.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://baycare.clearstep.health/covid19")!))
                    }
            }
  
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = controller
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
}

extension NSObjectProtocol {
    @discardableResult
    func setup(_ fn: (Self) -> Void) -> Self {
        fn(self)
        return self
    }
}

final class WebViewUIDelegate: NSObject, WKUIDelegate {
    static let instance = WebViewUIDelegate()
}


final class WebViewDelegate: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {

    static let instance = WebViewDelegate()

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        print("This doesn't fire so no error?", error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

WKWebView is depricated version but still webview will works fine, I had same issue and I was doing same but then instead of WKWenView I used web view

import UIKit
import WebKit

```
class PolicyVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
    
    var isPolicyView = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_arrow_left"), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(popView), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [barButton]
        setUpUI()
        
       }

    @objc func popView(){
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
    }
    
    func setUpUI(){
        
        if isPolicyView{
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.termsfeed.com/privacy-policy/68c4cdaeba7e146a7d72bf57654520e7")
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
            webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }else{
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.termsfeed.com/terms-conditions/0001db2c7a1061a55e2f933bb94102de")
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
            webView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: The URL "https://baycare.clearstep.health/covid19" also doesn't load using UIWebView. This answer doesn't work. :-(